# IOS - chat application using XMPP Protocol

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat

I am going to start an IOS application. In which I am going to implement the

- one to one chat
- one to many chat

with using the XMPP protocol.

I have searched over the internet. I have seen that "Xabber" (open source) did what I want. But It is available only in android.

I am new to this domain. So can anyone give some samples to do that functionality in IOS?

Comment: quickblox http://quickblox.com/developers/QuickBlox_Developers check it